# How to mock exec.Command for multiple unit tests in Go lang?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I just learnt unit testing functions that uses `exec.Command()` i.e., mocking `exec.Command()`. I went ahead to added more unit cases, but running into issues of not able to mock the output for different scenarios.

**Here is a sample code `hello.go` I'm trying to test...**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

var execCommand = exec.Command

func printDate() ([]byte, error) {
    cmd := execCommand("date")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    return out, err
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
    fmt.Println(printDate())
}
```

**Below is the test code `hello_test.go`...**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "testing"
)

var mockedExitStatus = 1
var mockedDate = "Sun Aug 20"
var expDate = "Sun Aug 20"

func fakeExecCommand(command string, args ...string) *exec.Cmd {
    cs := []string{"-test.run=TestHelperProcess", "--", command}
    cs = append(cs, args...)
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], cs...)
    cmd.Env = []string{"GO_WANT_HELPER_PROCESS=1"}
    return cmd
}

func TestHelperProcess(t *testing.T) {
    if os.Getenv("GO_WANT_HELPER_PROCESS") != "1" {
        return
    }

    // println("Mocked Data:", mockedDate)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, mockedDate)
    os.Exit(mockedExitStatus)
}

func TestPrintDate(t *testing.T) {
    execCommand = fakeExecCommand
    defer func() { execCommand = exec.Command }()

    out, err := printDate()
    print("Std out: ", string(out))
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected nil error, got %#v", err)
    }
    if string(out) != expDate {
        t.Errorf("Expected %q, got %q", expDate, string(out))
    }
}

func TestPrintDateUnableToRunError(t *testing.T) {
    execCommand = fakeExecCommand
    defer func() { execCommand = exec.Command }()

    mockedExitStatus = 1
    mockedDate = "Unable to run date command"
    expDate = "Unable to run date command"

    out, err := printDate()
    print("Std out: ", string(out))
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected nil error, got %#v", err)
    }
    if string(out) != expDate {
        t.Errorf("Expected %q, got %q", expDate, string(out))
    }
}
```

**`go test` fails for the second test `TestPrintDateUnableToRunError`...**

```
$ go test hello
Std out: Sun Aug 20Std out: Sun Aug 20--- FAIL: TestPrintDateTomorrow (0.01s)
    hello_test.go:62: Expected "Unable to run date command", got "Sun Aug 20"
FAIL
FAIL    hello   0.017s
```

Even though I'm trying to set the global `mockedDate` value inside the test case, it's still getting the global value that it was initialized with. **Is the global value not getting set? Or the changes to that global var is not getting updated in `TestHelperProcess`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution for this...

> Is the global value not getting set? Or the changes to that global var is not getting updated in TestHelperProcess?

Since in `TestPrintDate()`, `fakeExecCommand` is called instead of exec.Command, and calling `fakeExecCommand` runs `go test` to run only `TestHelperProcess()`, it's altogether a new invocation where only `TestHelperProcess()` will be executed. Since only `TestHelperProcess()` is called, the global variables aren't being set.

The solution would be to set the Env in the `fakeExecCommand`, and retrieve that in `TestHelperProcess()` and return those values.

*PS> `TestHelperProcess` is renamed to `TestExecCommandHelper`*, And few variables are renamed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

var mockedExitStatus = 0
var mockedStdout string

func fakeExecCommand(command string, args ...string) *exec.Cmd {
    cs := []string{"-test.run=TestExecCommandHelper", "--", command}
    cs = append(cs, args...)
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], cs...)
    es := strconv.Itoa(mockedExitStatus)
    cmd.Env = []string{"GO_WANT_HELPER_PROCESS=1",
        "STDOUT=" + mockedStdout,
        "EXIT_STATUS=" + es}
    return cmd
}

func TestExecCommandHelper(t *testing.T) {
    if os.Getenv("GO_WANT_HELPER_PROCESS") != "1" {
        return
    }

    // println("Mocked stdout:", os.Getenv("STDOUT"))
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, os.Getenv("STDOUT"))
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("EXIT_STATUS"))
    os.Exit(i)
}

func TestPrintDate(t *testing.T) {
    mockedExitStatus = 1
    mockedStdout = "Sun Aug 201"
    execCommand = fakeExecCommand
    defer func() { execCommand = exec.Command }()
    expDate := "Sun Aug 20"

    out, _ := printDate()
    if string(out) != expDate {
        t.Errorf("Expected %q, got %q", expDate, string(out))
    }
}

func TestPrintDateUnableToRunError(t *testing.T) {
    mockedExitStatus = 1
    mockedStdout = "Unable to run date command"
    execCommand = fakeExecCommand
    defer func() { execCommand = exec.Command }()

    expDate := "Unable to run date command"

    out, _ := printDate()
    // println("Stdout: ", string(out))
    if string(out) != expDate {
        t.Errorf("Expected %q, got %q", expDate, string(out))
    }
}
```

**`go test` results as below...** 
*(Purposely failing one test to show that the mock is working properly).*

```
 go test hello
--- FAIL: TestPrintDate (0.01s)
        hello_test.go:45: Expected "Sun Aug 20", got "Sun Aug 201"
FAIL
FAIL    hello   0.018s
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've posted, the `mockedDate` variable doesn't do anything. Neither the test, nor the call to `printDate()` are utilizing it, so the `TestPrintDateUnableToRunError()` test performs just like the tests before it.

If you were to add functionality to the `printDate()` function to return string of "Unable to run date command" (when that is the case), then your condition on line 62 would pass. That said, such checks should be unnecessary, when you have an error in the return values from `printDate()`. If the returned error is non-nil, the returned output string should be expected to be invalid (or empty, `""`).

I can't tell how you really want `printDate()` to fail, but as it stands, there's no way for it to return the values you're expecting in `TestPrintDateUnableToRunError()`.

Comment: I was trying to call some script actually, and that script could sometimes be not present... For asking here, I just used date as an example... Thanks.
By the way. I later realized that I can do it by making use of ENV variables.